# ckeditor custom template config

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I declare config for ckeditor as follows:

```
var ckconfig  = {
    uiColor: '#ffffff',
    stylesCombo_stylesSet: [],
    format_tags: "p;h2;h3;h4;div",
    contentsCss : '/js/admin/editorstyles/default.css',
    extraPlugins : 'stylesheetparser',
    scayt_autoStartup:true,
    toolbar_Full: [['Templates','Styles','Format','FontSize','TextColor', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline','-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList','-','Scayt','PasteText'],
    ['Image','Link', 'Unlink'], ['Undo', 'Redo'],['Source', 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']] 
}
```

and initiate as

```
$('textarea#b_description').ckeditor(ckconfig);
```

Which is fine, but how would I add a custom template file with this notation?

Answer (score 3):

If you go into ckeditor/plugins/templates/templates/default.js (based on file structure for version 3.6.2), you will see the definitions for templates.

Using this page as a guide -- http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Templates -- you should be able to accomplish whatever is necessary to create new templates.

You can declare an explicit list of template files to use inside your config.js file using the following notation:

```
config.templates_files = [ '/mytemplates.js' ];
```

For your specific notation, the line would be:

```
templates_files: [ '/mytemplates1.js', '/mytemplates2.js' ]
```

Comment: I need to get this content from a database. Can we do this.

Comment: Theoretically, you could define the template files list as an ajax function that returns an array. If that won't work, all I can think of would be to explore the documentation for PHP-instantiated (assuming you're using PHP) instances. You might be able to find a way to set the template list in PHP, which would make the data retrieval quite simple.

Comment: on ckeditor.js, I found this 'plugins/templates/templates/default.js'. I changed it to file which loads data from DB.  It worked. Thanks for the suggestion.